# how to protect "dynamically by ajax generated .js-file"?

Tags: ajax

)

i am a newbe with drupal7=>civicrm and found by chance an "open door" probably dynamically genrated by ajax:

=> https://{our domain}/crm/civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/
The browser shows this:

*// http://civicrm.org/licensing
//  Generated 17 May 2021 14:28:02
(function($) {
// Config settings
CRM.config.userFramework = "Drupal";
CRM.config.resourceBase = "https://machmit.aufstehen.de/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/";
CRM.config.packagesBase = "https://machmit.aufstehen.de/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/";
CRM.config.lcMessages = "de_DE";
CRM.config.locale = "de_DE";
CRM.config.cid = 15944;
$.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = CRM.config.dateInputFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
CRM.config.timeIs24Hr = false;
CRM.config.ajaxPopupsEnabled = true;
CRM.config.allowAlertAutodismissal = true;
CRM.config.resourceCacheCode = "JfC51";
// Merge entityRef settings
CRM.config.entityRef = $.extend({}, {"filters":{"Contact":[{"key":"contact_type","value":"Kontaktart"},{"key":"group","value":"Gruppe","entity":"GroupContact"},{"key":"tag","value":"Tag","entity":"EntityTag"},{"key":"city","value":"Stadt","type":"text","entity":"Address"},{"key":"postal_code","value":"Postleitzahl","type":"text","entity":"Address"},{"key":"state_province","value":"Bundesland","entity":"Address"},{"key":"country","value":"Land","entity":"Address"},{"key":"first_name","value":"Vorname","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"last_name","value":"Nachname","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"nick_name","value":"Nick Name","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"organization_name","value":"Employer name","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"gender_id","value":"Geschlecht","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"is_deceased","value":"Verstorben","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"}},{"key":"contact_id","value":"CiviCRM ID","type":"text"},{"key":"external_identifier","value":"Externe ID","type":"text"},{"key":"source","value":"Bezugsquelle","type":"text"}],"Email":{"0":{"key":"contact_id.contact_type","value":"Kontaktart","entity":"Contact"},"7":{"key":"contact_id.first_name","value":"Vorname","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"8":{"key":"contact_id.last_name","value":"Nachname","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"9":{"key":"contact_id.nick_name","value":"Nick Name","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"10":{"key":"contact_id.organization_name","value":"Employer name","type":"text","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"11":{"key":"contact_id.gender_id","value":"Geschlecht","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"12":{"key":"contact_id.is_deceased","value":"Verstorben","condition":{"contact_type":"Individual"},"entity":"Contact"},"13":{"key":"contact_id","value":"CiviCRM ID","type":"text"},"14":{"key":"contact_id.external_identifier","value":"Externe ID","type":"text","entity":"Contact"},"15":{"key":"contact_id.source","value":"Bezugsquelle","type":"text","entity":"Contact"}},"Activity":[{"key":"activity_type_id","value":"Aktivit\u00e4tstyp"},{"key":"status_id","value":"Status der Aktivit\u00e4t"}]},"links":{"Contact":[{"label":"New Individual","url":"/crm/civicrm/profile/create?reset=1&context=dialog&gid=4","type":"Individual","icon":"fa-user"},{"label":"New Organization","url":"/crm/civicrm/profile/create?reset=1&context=dialog&gid=5","type":"Organization","icon":"fa-building"},{"label":"New Household","url":"/crm/civicrm/profile/create?reset=1&context=dialog&gid=6","type":"Household","icon":"fa-home"}]}}, CRM.config.entityRef || {});
// Initialize CRM.url and CRM.formatMoney
CRM.url({back: '/crm/civicrm-placeholder-url-path?civicrm-placeholder-url-query=1', front: '/crm/civicrm-placeholder-url-path?civicrm-placeholder-url-query=1'});
CRM.formatMoney('init', false, "\u20ac 1.234,56");
// Localize select2
$.fn.select2.defaults.formatNoMatches = "Nichts gefunden.";
$.fn.select2.defaults.formatLoadMore = "Lade...";
$.fn.select2.defaults.formatSearching = "Suche...";
$.fn.select2.defaults.formatInputTooShort = function() {
return ($(this).data('api-entity') === 'contact' || $(this).data('api-entity') === 'Contact') ? "Hier Namen oder E-Mail-Adresse eintragen..." : "Einen Suchbegriff eingeben...";
};
// Localize jQuery UI
$.ui.dialog.prototype.options.closeText = "SchlieÃŸen";
// Localize jQuery DataTables
// Note the first two defaults set here aren't localization related,
// but need to be set globally for all DataTables.
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
"searching": false,
"jQueryUI": true,
"language": {
"emptyTable": "Nichts gefunden.",
"info":  "EintrÃ¤ge *START* bis *END* von insgesamt *TOTAL*",
"infoEmpty": "Zeige 0 bis 0 von 0 EintrÃ¤gen",
"infoFiltered": "(filtered from *MAX* total entries)",
"infoPostFix": "",
"thousands": ".",
"lengthMenu": "*MENU* EintrÃ¤ge anzeigen",
"loadingRecords": " ",
"processing": " ",
"zeroRecords": "Nichts gefunden.",
"paginate": {
"first": "Erste",
"last": "Letzte",
"next": "Weiter",
"previous": "ZurÃ¼ck"
}
}
});
// Localize strings for jQuery.validate
var messages = {
required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
remote: "Bitte korrigieren Sie dieses Feld.",
email: "Bitte geben Sie eine gÃ¼ltige E-Mailadresse ein.",
url: "Geben Sie eine gÃ¼ltige URL ein.",
date: "Bitte gebe ein gÃ¼ltiges Datum ein.",
dateISO: "Bitte gebe ein gÃ¼ltiges Datum ein (JJJJ-MM-TT).",
number: "Geben Sie eine gÃ¼ltige Zahl ein.",
digits: "Bitte gebe nur Ziffern ein. ",
creditcard: "Bitte geben Sie eine gÃ¼ltige Kreditkartennummer ein. ",
equalTo: "Bitte geben Sie die gleichen Werter noch einmal ein.",
accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
maxlength: $.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
minlength: $.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
rangelength: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
range: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
max: $.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
min: $.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
};
$.extend($.validator.messages, messages);

var params = {
errorClass: 'crm-inline-error alert-danger',
messages: {},
ignore: '.select2-offscreen, [readonly], :hidden:not(.crm-select2), .crm-no-validate',
ignoreTitle: true,
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
error.appendTo(element.parent('div.content'));
}
else {
error.insertAfter(element);
}
}
};
// use civicrm notifications when there are errors
params.invalidHandler = function(form, validator) {
// If there is no container for display then red text will still show next to the invalid fields
// but there will be no overall message. Currently the container is only available on backoffice pages.
if ($('#crm-notification-container').length) {
$.each(validator.errorList, function(k, error) {
$(error.element).parents('.crm-custom-accordion.collapsed').crmAccordionToggle();
$(error.element).crmError(error.message);
});
}
};
CRM.validate = {
_defaults: params,
params: {},
functions: []
};
// Load polyfill
if (!('Promise' in window)) {
CRM.loadScript(CRM.config.resourceBase + 'bower_components/es6-promise/es6-promise.auto.min.js');
}
})(jQuery);*

Is this the way it should be ???

Thanks a lot for any suggestion how to protect this....

Best regards
Dieter

Comment: I can't reproduce this either on a test site or the public demo http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. My guess is something about your web server configuration?

Comment: Hi Demerit,
thx ;-) 
The drupal7/civicrm is installed via yunohost.
WebServer is nginx and i did not change any configuration by myself.

There are installed these addons also:
#  yunohost app list
apps:
  0: civicrm_drupal7
  1: my_webapp
  2: phpmyadmin
  3: redirect

best regards
Dieter